# Fill form fields in existing PDF files with nativescript / angular

Tags: angular, pdf, nativescript

I'm looking for a way to fill form fields in existing PDF files with my NativeScript/Angular app.

I already found that pdf editing in NativeScript seems to be a challenging task but I didn't found any examples how to deal with form fields.

I'm new to Nativescript so I don't really know how to get a hand on this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, you want to fill the form within the PDF programatically Or just load the PDF and let user fill the form? If you want user to fill the forms, you may use [nativescript-pspdfkit](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-pspdfkit)

Comment: Some form fields has to be filled programmatically (e.g. customer name, address, etc.), but this request seems to fulfilled by PSPDFKit too. But I was looking for a free library to achieve that (in C# we're using PDFsharp) before going to paid solutions.

Comment: There is [MuPDF](https://www.mupdf.com/index.html) but when compared to paid SDKs this is not really up to the mark.

Comment: After some more research I think I have to use a commercial library like PSPDFKit to fulfill this request. The second option would be to implement it in my C# web API and use something like PDFsharp to fill the pdf files and send it back to the client app. Not the smartest solution and I'm loosing offline functionality at this point, but technically it would work.